How do I "force" a hamiltonian to describe a particle moving with a velocity in a specific direction?
I want to describe a system of two particles, each in a local harmonic potential, with an intermolecular potential between them. One of the particles is moving toward the other one. I wish to be able to find the probability of the particle not moving being excited as a function of the velocity of the other particle. How do I include "velocity" in my Hamiltonian? Surely it will need time dependence, but how do I incorporate a "velocity" within my Hamiltonian such that I can find a wave function that's a function of coordinates, time, and a velocity? The endgoal is to be able compute the amplitudes $\langle x_1, x_2, \dot{x_2}, n_1, n_2,  t|x_1,x'_2, \dot{x_2}, n_1', n_2,t\rangle$, where $x_i$ is the position of the $i$th particle and $n_i$ is the state of the $i$th particle.

Quanta don't have velocities. Your Hamiltonian doesn't describe the state of your system to begin with. It describes the interaction in your system. None of the two answers seem to mention that a two-quantum wave function depends on two copies of physical space, i.e. it's a function of six coordinates, not three. And while your two quanta can initially be in pure single quantum momentum states given by two classical momenta $p_1$ and $p_2$, the interaction will populate the diagonals and the physical meaning of motion in space will be lost.

Velocity/momentum is contained within the wave function - different initial wave functions correspond to different initial velocities.
E.g., if we take Hamiltonian $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, the velocity operator is determined by the standard prescription as
$$
\hat{v}=\hat{\dot{x}}=\frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{x},H]= \frac{p}{m}
$$
(This is a definition of velocity operator in Schrödinger picture - not to be confused with identically looking Heisenberg equation of motion for the position operator.)
A particle with wave function $\psi=Ae^{ikx}=Ae^{i\frac{mVx}{\hbar}}$ will have expectatoon value of velocity
$$\langle \hat{v}\rangle=\frac{\hbar k}{m}=V$$

You can "imprint" an average momentum on a wave function by multiplying the wave function by a plane wave. If you have a real-valued wave function $\psi(\vec{x})$, then the wave function $e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}\psi(\vec{x})$ will have an average momentum $\hbar\vec{k}$, and the center of the wave packet will move with this momentum (for a time, anyway; the external potential will modify this; but this gives you an initial momentum).
